# How do I spawn 5 lasers at time intervals in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know about InvokeRepeating but I want to spawn 5 laser/bullets, wait 0.5 seconds, repeat 3 times, and wait for another 3 seconds before repeating again. I don't think InvokeRepeating will work for this.

Comment: Do you already have code that spawns 5 lasers? Do you already have code that waits then repeats? How much of this do you already have? What have you already tried?

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought I was looking for recommendations. I spent some time digging around in the guidelines and I think it means that I can't have questions asking for recommendations about coding. I don't really think I'm asking for recommendations here. Could you help me out?

Comment: Why did you guys close the question? Please reopen it. Please.

Comment: I didn't vote to close it, and I voted to re-open it, but I'm guessing because it didn't show much research effort. typically a question ought include some code, or at least pseudocode, and to show what you were trying to do in your research. If someone is asking how to do something and appears to not even have started on it, they are essentially just asking for a tutorial recommendation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just started unity. Haha, I'm way better now. Sorry if it didn't show much research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you would probably rather use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for that.

Coroutines are like small little temporary `Update` methods - indeed they are executed right after the `Update` call until the next `yield` statement. Unity provides e.g. [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) [yield instruction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) that uses the native underlying code clock to determine when the time is passed.

By `yield`ing you basically tell Unity to "pause" the execution here, render that frame and continue from here in the next frame.

```
IEnumerator LaserRoutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            SpawnFiveBullets();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

You have to start this in a `MonoBehaviour` via [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

```
StartCoroutine(LaserRoutine ());
```

Or if it shall happen permanently you could also directly make it

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            SpawnFiveBullets();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question. When you run a coroutine, does it pause your code or does it run in the background?

Comment: @CodingTigers It releases control when it hits `yield return`, until the thing after `yield return` says to resume execution. If the MonoBehaviour that called `StartCoroutine` is disabled/destroyed or until the coroutine is stopped with `StopCoroutine`, then it won't resume. See my answer below for an example.

Comment: @CodingTigers as Ruzihm already said .. it does neither ;) Coroutines are always executed in the main thread right after the `Update` call and run their code until the next `yield` .. Unity provides the `WaitForSeconds` yield instruction that uses the native clock in order to determine when the time has passed. With every `yield` call you basically tell Unity "pause" the routine here, render that frame and continue from where you left in the next frame.

Comment: @derHugo excellent explanation as usual! I'll throw you an upvote if you add that to the answer ;)

Comment: @Ruzihm ha saw you posted basically the same thing at the same time ^^

Comment: @derHugo I see the "if it shall happen permanently" part so this isn't a critique of your answer. I just happened to think about this question. Do you know if there is a way to `StopCoroutine` a "coroutined" `Start` or other magic method?

Comment: @Ruzihm probably only `StopAllCoroutines` or in case of the `Start` .. disable/destroy the component ^^ since anyway there would be no way to start it again except you implement it somewhere ^^

Answer (score 1):

I would use a coroutine for this, using `WaitForSeconds` to pause:

```
Coroutine laserSpawningCoroutine = null;

public void StartSpawningLasers()
{
    StopSpawningLasers();
    laserSpawningCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DoSpawnLasers());
}

public void StopSpawningLasers()
{
    if (laserSpawningCoroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(laserSpawningCoroutine);
    }
    laserSpawningCoroutine = null;
}

IEnumerator DoSpawnLasers()
{
    WaitForSeconds halfSecondPause = new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    WaitForSeconds threeSecondPause = new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            SpawnFiveLasers();
            yield return halfSecondPause;
        }
        yield return threeSecondPause;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use condition here to check how much projectile fired.

```
int counter;
bool fired;
        
if(!fired)
{
   InvokeRepeating("LaunchProjectile", 0f, 0.5f);
   fired = true;
} else if(counter >=3)
{
   Invoke("LaunchProjectile", 3f);
   counter = 0;
   fired = false;
}
void LaunchProjectile()
{
    
    // do instantiate bullet here
    if(counter == 3)
    {
       CancelInvoke("LaunchProjectile");
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Won't this cause LaunchProjectile to be called every half second? Asker is very clear that there needs to be periods of 3 seconds where no projectiles are launched...

Comment: yes asker needs .5 seconds delay. and 3 seconds after 3 shots.

Comment: counter never reaches 3 now... But anyway shouldn't you do something like `CancelInvoke` in the second block? Otherwise, there are **1** never going to be a period of 3 seconds where no projectiles are launched and **2** going to be ever more projectiles spawned every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @Ruzihm I think InvokeRepeating reapeat itself once activated no need in update.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. As I've said already, asker needs there to be periods of 3 seconds where it doesn't get called every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: No asker wants is fire three times in .5 seconds delay and after 3 has fired wait 3 seconds and reapeat again 3 shots .5 delay.

Comment: So, step through your code. 
**0 seconds** counter =0 InvokeRepeating called. LP called once (good);
**0.5 seconds** counter= 0 LP called once (good);
**1.0 seconds** counter=0 LP called once (good);
**1.5 seconds** counter=0 LP called once (should not be called);
**2.0 seconds** counter=0 LP called once (should not be called);

Comment: Even if counter is fixed, 
**0 seconds** counter =0 InvokeRepeating called. LP called once (good);
**0.5 seconds** counter= 1 LP called once (good);
**1.0 seconds** counter=2 LP called once (good);
**1.5 seconds** counter=3 LP called once (should not be called);
**2.0 seconds** counter=0 LP called once (should not be called);

Comment: Assuming this code is meant to be inside of the `LaunchProjectile` method

Comment: This still calls LP once at 1.5 seconds, 2.0 seconds, 2.5 seconds, etc... As mentioned before, would you consider do something like `CancelInvoke` in the second block?

Comment: @ Ruzihm I edit it.

Comment: It'd probably be better to specify the method name so it doesn't interfere with anything else. `CancelInvoke("LaunchProjectile");`